# Fix wierd lighting/shaders with color ramp material

Tags: objects, shaders, light, eevee-render-engine

I'm having trouble figuring out why there are those weird triangle glitchy imperfections in the shaders of this low poly car. It's a fairly flat object but there are those outline triangle things near the outlines of the faces.

[image]

Comment: Have you check for z-fighting issues caused by overlapping faces?

Comment: Yes, there are no overlapping faces

Comment: Can you post your blendfile here? Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=qOnajwNX" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/qOnajwNX/)